# What is the Invoke property on a Func<T>?

Tags: c#

This compiles but the second method is flagged as "Function is recursive on all paths." and calling it results in a StackOverflowException. Intellisense (w/ ReSharper) supplied Invoke as a property.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void MyMethod(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public void MyMethod(Func<string> getValue)
    {
        MyMethod(getValue.Invoke);
    }
}
```

Changing it to this works as expected:

```
    public void MyMethod(Func<string> getValue)
    {
        MyMethod(getValue.Invoke());
    }
```

What's going on here? Is this just Intellisense weirdness or is there actually an Invoke property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the `Invoke` *method* - but being converted via method group conversion... which is then recursing. See if this makes it any clearer - it's the equivalent code:

```
public void MyMethod(Func<string> getValue)
{
    Func<string> func = getValue.Invoke;
    MyMethod(func); // Eek, recursive!
}
```

(I'll assume for the moment that you're familiar with method group conversion as one way of obtaining a delegate instance. Let me know if you're not and I'll go into more details.)

Comment: I'm familiar with method group conversion only to the extent that it means there's no longer a need to new up event handler delegates when adding them to an event. That's the only time I've knowingly run into it. It's disappointing that Intellisense does not prompt with the method signature.

Comment: @Jamie: Well doesn't it just fill in the name, as it does normally? It's up to you to make it a method invocation.

Comment: ReSharper adds the method invocation automatically so I guess I shouldn't be too hard on Intellisense. But it's confusing because normally you can't have a method and a property with the same signature.

Comment: @Jamie: And indeed you can't - `Invoke` *isn't* a property. The unusual situation here is that both the method group conversion *and the method invocation* are valid.

Answer (score -2):

To add to Jon's answer, note that the reason you can't find the `Invoke` member in the object browser is because, per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx):

> Note
>
> The **common language runtime** provides an `Invoke` method for each
>   delegate type, with the same signature as the delegate. You do not
>   have to call this method explicitly from C#, Visual Basic, or Visual
>   C++, because the compilers call it automatically. The `Invoke` method is
>   useful in reflection when you want to find the signature of the
>   delegate type.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense to me.  The `Invoke` method is perfectly well visible on every delegate through Intellisense and through the object browser.

Comment: @mquander would be great if you could furnish a screenshot of `Invoke` on a delegate type in the object browser, I can't seem to find it in mine.

Comment: OK there's something I don't understand going on with the object browser. I'll investigate further tomorrow. In the mean time [I am not making this up](http://imgur.com/MdI6E) !